# SAX Confusing Two Nodes With Same Name in XML

Tags: python, xml, sqlite, parsing, sax

I have an XML that I need to parse in python using SAX.

Here is a small part of my XML :

```
<MovieRating>
  <Movie Id="1">
    <Title>Father Figures</Title>
    <Duration>01:53:00</Duration>
    <Description>Upon learning that their mother has been lying to them for years about their allegedly deceased father, two fraternal twin brothers hit the road in order to find him.</Description>
    <Release_Date>2017-12-22</Release_Date>
    <Image_URL>https://image.com/1.jpg</Image_URL>
    <Country>USA</Country>
    <Genres>
      <Genre Id="5">
        <Title>Comedy</Title>
        <Description>None</Description>
      </Genre>
    </Genres>
    </Movies>
</MovieRating>
```

I am trying to parse it and save it into a DB, in the following matter:

```
import sqlite3
import xml.sax 

class MoviesHandler(xml.sax.ContentHandler):
    def __init__(self):
        self.sql_attr_name = None
        self.sql_attrs = dict()
        self.conn = None

    def startDocument(self):
        self.conn = sqlite3.connect('moviez_sax.db')
        c = self.conn.cursor()
        c.execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS MOVIE')
        c.execute('''
                    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Movie (
                Id           INTEGER        NOT NULL,
                Title        VARCHAR (1000) NOT NULL,
                Duration     TIME           NOT NULL,
                Description  VARCHAR (5000),
                Release_Date DATE           NOT NULL,
                Image_URL    VARCHAR (1000),
                Country      VARCHAR (150), 
                PRIMARY KEY (Id)
            );''');

    def endDocument(self):
        self.conn.commit()
        self.conn.close()


    def startElement(self, xml_name, xml_attrs):
        #print("start element", xml_name)
        if xml_name.lower() == 'movierating':
            pass
        if xml_name.lower() == 'movie':
            self.sql_attr_name = None
            self.sql_attrs = {
                'Id' : '',
                'Title' : '',
                'Duration' : '',
                'Description' : '',
                'Release_Date' : '',
                'Image_URL' : '',
                'Country':''
            }
            self.sql_attrs['Id'] += xml_attrs['Id']
        elif xml_name.lower() in ['id', 'title', 'duration', 'description' , 'release_date', 'image_url','country']:
            self.sql_attr_name = xml_name
        else:
            pass

    def characters(self, text):
        if self.sql_attr_name is not None:
            self.sql_attrs[self.sql_attr_name] += text

    def endElement(self, xml_name):
        if xml_name.lower() == 'movie':
            c = self.conn.cursor()
            c.execute('INSERT INTO MOVIE(Id,Title,Duration,\
                       Description,Release_Date,Image_URL, Country) VALUES \
                       (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)',
                      (self.sql_attrs['Id'].strip(),
                       self.sql_attrs['Title'].strip(),
                       self.sql_attrs['Duration'].strip(),
                       self.sql_attrs['Description'].strip(),
                       self.sql_attrs['Release_Date'].strip(),
                       self.sql_attrs['Image_URL'].strip(),
                       self.sql_attrs['Country'].strip())) 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = xml.sax.make_parser()
    parser.setContentHandler(MovieRatingHandler())
    parser.parse(open('movies.xml','r'))
```

My problem is, whenever i read `self.sql_attrs['Title'].strip()`, it is reading the TITLE node from both nodes : Movie and Genre

And it is saving the value of both concatenated. Like in that example, the value i'm getting for title is :

```
Father Figures \n Comedy
```

Is there a way to specify to SAX which node title but also which node path to read ? Because i have many nodes with same names but i wanna read "Movie" alone and "Genre" alone and save them in two different tables.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to record an event in case of both `genre` and `movie`. You will then use a stack/list to push the current node.

You should maintain a node based dict in that case too. Below is just an update to your code, not the most efficient one, but shows how you can expand your example

```
import sqlite3
import xml.sax

class MoviesHandler(xml.sax.ContentHandler):
    def __init__(self):
        self.sql_attr_name = None
        self.nodes = []
        self.sql_attrs = dict()
        self.conn = None

    def startDocument(self):
        self.conn = sqlite3.connect('moviez_sax.db')
        c = self.conn.cursor()
        c.execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS MOVIE')
        c.execute('''
                    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Movie (
                Id           INTEGER        NOT NULL,
                Title        VARCHAR (1000) NOT NULL,
                Duration     TIME           NOT NULL,
                Description  VARCHAR (5000),
                Release_Date DATE           NOT NULL,
                Image_URL    VARCHAR (1000),
                Country      VARCHAR (150), 
                PRIMARY KEY (Id)
            );''');

    def endDocument(self):
        self.conn.commit()
        self.conn.close()


    def startElement(self, xml_name, xml_attrs):
        #print("start element", xml_name)
        if xml_name.lower() == 'movierating':
            pass
        if xml_name.lower() == 'genre':
            self.nodes.append(xml_name)
            self.sql_attrs[xml_name] = {
                'Title': '',
                'Description': '',
            }
        if xml_name.lower() == 'movie':
            self.nodes.append(xml_name)
            self.sql_attr_name = None
            self.sql_attrs[xml_name] = {
                'Id' : '',
                'Title' : '',
                'Duration' : '',
                'Description' : '',
                'Release_Date' : '',
                'Image_URL' : '',
                'Country':''
            }
            self.sql_attrs[xml_name]['Id'] += xml_attrs['Id']
        elif xml_name.lower() in ['id', 'title', 'duration', 'description' , 'release_date', 'image_url','country']:
            self.sql_attr_name = xml_name
        else:
            self.sql_attr_name = None
            pass

    def characters(self, text):
        if self.sql_attr_name is None or len(self.nodes) == 0:
            return

        if self.sql_attrs[self.nodes[-1]] is not None:
            self.sql_attrs[self.nodes[-1]][self.sql_attr_name] += text

    def endElement(self, xml_name):
        if xml_name.lower() in ['movie', 'genre']:
            self.nodes.pop()

        if xml_name.lower() == 'movie':
            c = self.conn.cursor()
            c.execute('INSERT INTO MOVIE(Id,Title,Duration,\
                       Description,Release_Date,Image_URL, Country) VALUES \
                       (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)',
                      (self.sql_attrs[xml_name]['Id'].strip(),
                       self.sql_attrs[xml_name]['Title'].strip(),
                       self.sql_attrs[xml_name]['Duration'].strip(),
                       self.sql_attrs[xml_name]['Description'].strip(),
                       self.sql_attrs[xml_name]['Release_Date'].strip(),
                       self.sql_attrs[xml_name]['Image_URL'].strip(),
                       self.sql_attrs[xml_name]['Country'].strip()))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = xml.sax.make_parser()
    parser.setContentHandler(MoviesHandler())
    parser.parse(open('movies.xml','r'))
```

And as you can see the debug session the titles are correct

[image: Working]

Comment: Thank you. I have one question I didn't understand: In case I have more nodes than 2, how do you deal with it in characters()? I have difficulty understanding the line with self.nodes[-1] and how i can modify it in case of more than 2 nodes.

Comment: You will duplicate it like the `if xml_name.lower() == 'genre':
            self.nodes.append(xml_name)` and `[-1]` makes sure you get the latest element data, so change needed in that. Also you need to have corresponding pop in `if xml_name.lower() in ['movie', 'genre']:
            self.nodes.pop()` updated as well for other tags

Comment: Worked!! Thanks so much :)

Comment: Glad to be of some help :-)